# Можно ли сказать так "Совершить метаморфозу"?

Tags: значение-слов

Можно ли сказать так "Совершить метаморфозу"?

Answer (score 1):

Совершить метаморфозу,конечно нельзя. Метаморфоза - это полное изменение, превращение кого-,чего-л. Т.е. метаморфоза происходит сама  по себя, без чего-л. или кого-либо участия. Поэтому можно сказать: с чем,- кем-л произошла метаморфоза, или что-либо претерпело метаморфозу.

Comment: Серж, есть и переносное значение Метаморфоза(шутлив.) - сильные изменения, превращения. Их можно совершить кому-то.

Comment: Людмила, мне известно о переносном значении. Но мне такое употребление тоже кажется непривычным. Даже в словаре ***Глагольной сочетаемости непредметных имён*** слово изменение не указано.

Comment: Людмила, вообще-то это "переносное" значение давно стало основным. Мы только о нем и говорим. Про бабочек давно все забыли.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел только одно подобное вхождение в нацкопусе.

> Необходимо было поэтому **совершить** над имуществом весьма оригинальную **метаморфозу**: сделать из родового благоприобретенным. [К. Н. Леонтьев. Сквозь нашу призму (1880)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

Вообще метаморфозу **претерпевают**, в редких случаях, когда надо подчеркнуть активность действия - **производят**.

Употребления "Совершить метаморфозу" следует избегать.

Comment: _behemothus: Нашел только одно подобное вхождение в нацко**р**пусе_. === Есть ещё: _Не потому трудно было поверить этим слухам, чтоб Балалайкин неспособен был **совершить** все эти **метаморфозы**_... [М.Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. В среде умеренности и аккуратности (1874-1877)]

Comment: Спасибо,друзья.

Answer (score 1):

> "Совершить метаморфозу"?

Так говорят:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[**И не только Чехов...**](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%22%20%22%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%83%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=3EFHVsjOBMu5sQG554_QAw#q=%22%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%22%20%22%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%83%22&newwindow=1&tbm=bks&start=0)

Comment: Слава, а лично Вы так сказали бы, до того ка найти эти результаты? Мне кажется странным такое употребление,ведь метаморфозы это процесс, который происходит в организме. В переносном - любое преобразование.

Comment: _Серж: Слава, а лично Вы так сказали бы, до того..._ === А _до того_ я, по-моему, вообще обходился без этого слова. Наверное, использовал какие-то русские синонимы...